# Cooccurrence Count in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a Pandas Dataframe as follows:

```
tokens
-----------
t1 t2 t3 t1
t2 t10 t10
t1 t1 t3
```

All I want is to get the co-occurrence frequencies as 3 separate columns:

```
token1  token2  count
  t1      t1      2
  t1      t2      1
  t1      t3      4
  t2      t3      1
  t2     t10      2
 t10     t10      1
```

This would potentially be applied to a huge dataset so any suggestions on the speed/performance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create combinations with 2 values for each splitted value, flatten it, sorting and count with `Counter`, last create tuples and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
from collections import Counter
from  itertools import combinations
L = [(*k, v) for k, v in Counter([tuple(sorted(y)) for x in df['tokens'] 
             for y in combinations(x.split(), 2)]).items()]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['token1','token2','count'])
print (df)
  token1 token2  count
0     t1     t2      2
1     t1     t3      4
2     t1     t1      2
3     t2     t3      1
4    t10     t2      2
5    t10    t10      1
```